# Data type which can represent multiple different classes with some common properties without inheritance

Tags: c#, class, object, unity-game-engine, overloading

I am working with c# in unity. I have class called CarPart which derives from MonoBehaviour (M.B. is base class for every unity script). In this class I have declared specific car parts classes which can't derive from any base class because unity inspector wouldn't show their properties, but they require mono behaviour so I declared them inside class (CarPart) which does derive from MonoBehaviour.

```
public class CarPart : MonoBehaviour {

    [System.Serializable] //required to show full objects in inspector
    public class Chassis {
        //common properties for all car parts
        public GameObject prefab;
        public int price;
        //specific properties for every car part
        public bool AWD;
        public int suspensionDepth;
        //specific implementation of equip for chassis
        public void equip() {
            //instantiate chassis as root object 
        }
    }
    [System.Serializable] //required to show full objects in inspector
    public class Engine {
        //common properties for all car parts
        public GameObject prefab;
        public int price;
        //specific properties for every car part
        public bool supportsAddOnExhaust;
        public int power;
        //specific implementation of Equip for engine
        public void Equip() {
            //instantiate engine as child object of chassis in hierarchy 
        }
    }
    //this code is heavily simplified
}
```

Then I have class VehicleConfig which is component of manager game object (this G.O. is active during entire game). VehicleConfig is communicating with GUI and based on GUI inputs it configures vehicle. It also has declared all car components which will be later assigned with specific values from inspector (power, suspensionDepth) and 3D models (prefab).

```
public class VehicleConfig : CarPart{
    public Chassis[] chassis; //assigned from inspector
    public Engine[] engines;  //assigned from inspector    
    //and more car components like these two...
    //arrays because there will be multiple to chose from each type        

    public void Setup (unknownDataType component) {
        component.Equip;
        DoSomethingWithCommonVariables(component.price, component.prefab);
    }
    //method called from GUI example:
    public void MountFirstEngine() {
        Setup(engines[0]);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I have a lot more specific car components than just Engine and Chassis and all of them have also a lot more common methods with specific implementation then just Equip(). Also Setup() is a little more complicated than example above. So I want Setup() to be overloaded with some datatype which can represent all the common methods and properties of all car parts(Engine, Chassis...) so then I could overload Setup() with for example Engines[0] converted to that special datatype. I know that there is different approach to implement this functionality with abstract class with all common abstract methods from which would be classes like Engine or Chassis derived and would provide certain implementation for those methods but as I mentioned earlier, unity inspector is not able to show member variables of derived classes. If anyone has an advice, idea or completely different approach. I would really appreciate mentioning it :) thx in advance.

Comment: You can represent all your common methods and properties with interface. Then your method takes that interface as the `unknownDataType`

Comment: You can try using more than one interface: `public class VehicleConfig : MonoBehaviour, CarPart`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what problem you had with the abstract classes, but you can use abstract classes to achieve what you want and have the properties available in the inspector:

```
public abstract class CarElement
{
  //common properties for all car parts
  public GameObject prefab;
  public int price;
  public abstract void Equip();
}

[System.Serializable] //required to show full objects in inspector
public class Chassis : CarElement
{
    //specific properties for every car part
    public bool AWD;
    public int suspensionDepth;
    public override void Equip() { }
}

[System.Serializable] //required to show full objects in inspector
public class Engine : CarElement
{
    //specific properties for every car part
    public bool supportsAddOnExhaust;
    public int power;
    public override void Equip(){ }
}

public class VehicleConfig : CarPart
{
    public Chassis[] chassis; //assigned from inspector
    public Engine[] engines;  //assigned from inspector    
    //and more car components like these two...
    //arrays because there will be multiple to chose from each type        

    public void Setup(CarElement component)
    {
          component.Equip();
          DoSomethingWithCommonVariables(component.price, component.prefab);
    }
    //method called from GUI example:
    public void MountFirstEngine()
    {
        Setup(engines[0]);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the most obvious solution, I was missing that inspector only hides properties of classes derived from MonoBehaviour, so I did it this way except that I put all the car parts classes (engine, chassis...) inside class that is derived from mono behaviour because I need car parts classes to be able to use methods provided by MonoBehaviour. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can store common data in a separate object. I would suggest `CarBase`

```
public class CarBase
{
    public GameObject prefab;
    public int price;
}
```

Then, create an interface that you have to implement for your method. I suggest `ICarEquip`

```
public interface ICarEquip
{
    public void Equip();
}
```

Now, for any car part that you want to create, derive it from Unity's `MonoBehaviour` and your own `ICarEquip`

```
public class Engine : MonoBehaviour, ICarEquip
{
    // Attach your CarBase information
    [System.Serializable]
    CarBase carBase;

    // Specific properties
    public bool doesSupportAddonExhaust;
    public int power;

    // Implement your interface methods
    public void Equip()
    {

    }
}
```

You are not going to get around the fact that your car part classes differ from each other, but you will greatly benefit from the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.

Your `VehicleConfig` class will have to change how it accesses and applies these components. I would not make it implement `CarBase`, as it's not a type of CarBase. Your `VehicleConfig` will take on more of a [Mediator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern). It will interact with different car parts in their own ways.